# how to compress uipickerview with compressed cell

Tags: objective-c

How to compress `UIPickerView` with a compressed cell? I mean when I compress a `UIPickerView` my cell text is also compressed or stretched.  Can  anybody help me ?
I use

```
dataPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.5);
```

to compress the `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement viewForRow method to do so.

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:       (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

```
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
[label setNumberOfLines:NSIntegerMax];
[label setText:[array objectAtIndex:row]];
return label;
```

}

Comment: if you want to do show picker for iPhone ans iPad differently, you can  simply set the frame for picker in different xibs